# And I feel I know nothing about you - beyond your name that is

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

This is a line I came across in Amitav Ghosh's The Hungry Tide

> *And I feel I know nothing about you - beyond your name **that is**.*

I know the meaning of "that is", it is used to provide some extra information, but here that meaning is not likely to be true. And I never came across "that is" used in this way.

Comment: You can think of it like this... *And I feel I know nothing about you. (But actually, I know one thing about you--your name.) And "that nothing about you" is beyond your name.*

Answer (score 1):

> I feel I know nothing about you

is the statement. Then the speaker decides to modify that statement with the additional information of:

> beyond your name, that is.

Here, the word *beyond* is used to mean *except for* or *aside from* and used as such, is expressing that, while the speaker *does* know the person's name, they feel like they know nothing *else*.

In this case, the modifying phrase is added to call out the exception to the general *knowing nothing* comment.  It makes the statement more correct as both parties know that the speaker actually *does* know something about the other… their name.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of its meaning like this...

> And I feel I know nothing about you. (But actually, I know one thing about you--your name.) And "that nothing about you" is beyond your name.

Here is how I parsed the sentence,

> And I feel [(I know nothing about you) -- (beyond your name) that is].

To understand it, I needed to rearrange it a little,

> And I feel [(I know nothing about you), and that (nothing about you) is (beyond your name)].

Comment: @snailplane I agree. I think we can interpret it both ways. However, even as a unit (*that is to say*, *that is what I would like to add*), the *that* part is still have some meaning. I mean that the *that* refers whatever has just been said. I tried to cram whatever has just been said into (nothing about you). If I could make [nothing about you] a furigana as in Japanese, I would reformat that line without hesitation.